# Auto update Google Sheet on edit Event using onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, autocomplete, event-handling, switch-statement

I want to auto update the author in author field in Google Sheet File when the author submit Content URL to the File. Basically i will get email of active user (author) and update fixed name with given email into the field.

This is my code but it not work.

Could Anyone Figure out why it's not work for me. Thanks

```
function onEdit(e){

var row = e.range.getRow();
Logger.log(row);
//var actSpreadsheet = e.source.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var actSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Content nào đó");
//Logger.log(e.value);
  if (Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() == "vulinh246@gmail.com")
{
Logger.log("Content 1 đang đăng nhập");
actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Content 1");
}



/* var  textlog = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log( textlog); */
var  textlog = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 switch(textlog){

case "linh.kcnamata@gmail.com":
  Logger.log("Content 1 đang đăng nhập");
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy") );
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Content 1");
  break;
case "thanlinh246@gmail.com":
  Logger.log("Content 2 đang đăng nhập");
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy") );
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Content 2");
  break;
case "vulinh246@gmail.com":
  Logger.log("Content 4 đang đăng nhập");
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "dd/MM/yyyy") );
  actSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue("Content 4");
  break;
} 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Session.getActiveUser() requires permission.  The scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` 
onEdit() trigger is a simple trigger and cannot perform functions that require permission.

Comment: Could You tell me how to Trigger functions that require permission ?

Comment: More info, all the preset user i used in my Google Sheet File had had permission.

Comment: You need to use an installable trigger.  You can create programmatically (check documentation) or you can use trigger menu from editor